# What's up with this broken Java Random.nextInt(long) behavior?

Tags: java, random

I discovered the hard way that this method seems to fail miserably when you feed it a power of 2. Given two Random objects of different seeds, it seems that the first integer they return when asked to return an integer between 0 (inclusive) and and a power of two (exclusive) is *always* the same; the seeds don't matter. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random mRandom;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        mRandom = new Random(i);            
        System.out.println(mRandom.nextInt((int) Math.pow(2, 4)));
    }
}

Console:
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
```

I chose 2^4 arbitrarily, but it seems to work for any power of two. What's going on? Furthermore, how can I avoid this?

Comment: The seed may not be significantly large enough to cause a drift in initial value

Comment: What version of Java are you on? I think this was fixed in Java 7.

Comment: @corsiKa, Java 7 has same effect.

Comment: change to mRandom = new Random((int)Math.pow(2,i)); and see that on step 9 it will start to generate different numbers - 11, 11, 12, 10 ...

Comment: @corsiKa, I'm actually using 6.

Comment: I can reproduce it on 1.7.0_10-b18, x64 Linux.

Comment: From the java doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29, there is a special case when the argument of nextInt(int n) is a power of 2. Why this causes this behaviour is something I am still trying to figure out

Answer (score 6):

This problem occurs due to 2 reasons.

1. Same seed for `Random` class.
2. At `nextInt(int n)`, if n is power of 2

### 1. Same seed for Random class.

Because, you have initiated new `Random` instance with new `seed` value which has influence on the `nextInt` value generation. According to Java docs of [Random(long seed)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28long%29).

> Creates a new random number generator using a single long seed. The seed is the initial value
>   of the internal state of the
>   pseudorandom number generator which is maintained by method next(int).
>
> ```
> The invocation new Random(seed) is equivalent to:
>
>  Random rnd = new Random();
>  rnd.setSeed(seed);
> ```

---

If you try to generate random value, without `new seed` than it will generate real random value, even though new instance of `Random` class.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    mRandom = new Random();   // Without seed         
    System.out.println(mRandom.nextInt((int) Math.pow(2, 4)));
}
```

**Output:** 2 1 12 4 3 9 9 8 2 9

### 2. At nextInt(int n), if n is power of 2

Besides this, [Random#nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) has effect of  power of 2. If n is a power of 2 it will return `(int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31)` which will always same for same n. According to `nextInt` Algorithm,

```
public int nextInt(int n) {
   if (n <= 0)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");

   if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
     return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

   int bits, val;
   do {
       bits = next(31);
       val = bits % n;
   } while (bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
   return val;
 }
```

Comment: I think OPs problem is with the fact that ten different seeds produce the same random number.

Comment: I don't follow. How does this relate to the range being a power of 2? That's the only time this bug occurs. Also, I unfortunately do need to use a seed, as the random behavior cannot be identical across sessions. On top of that, the range is specified by the user (not directly), so I need a way to avoid that behavior every time. I guess I can fix it buy just asking for the nextInt() when I instantiate the Random object, but that seems hacky...

Comment: @Masud, changing the range to a non-power of two fixes the bug.

Comment: It's not always the same. If you run it with `pow(2,8)` for 100 cycles you start to see it flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Math.random and Math.pow together for more simplicity if you wanted.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int pows = (int) Math.pow(2, 4);
int random = (int)(Math.random()*pows);            
    System.out.println(""+random);
}
```